# Validating multiple fields in a form - Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to validate three fields within my form. I have written the code for them and thought they would work. The only problem I'm having is that they're not done in a sequence. If i submit the form without filling in anything, it picks up the email validation.If i fill in the first name, again skips the first name and surname validation and goes straight to email. I tried to make it work in a sequence so first name first then surname and email. Any help would be appreciated.

JS

```
        function validateForm() {
            var fname = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["fname"].value;
            if (fname == "") {
                alert("Firstname must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
        function validateForm() {
            var sname = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["sname"].value;
            if (sname == "") {
                alert("Surname must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
        function validateForm() { 
            var email = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["email"].value;
            if (email == "") {
                alert("Email must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

HTML

```
<form name="buyProductForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <fieldset id="field1">
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>


        <label for="name">Firstname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your first name" ><br>

        <label for="name">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Enter your surname"><br>

        <label for="email">Email Adress:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" ><br>
```

Comment: You're using the same name for 3 different functions.

Comment: By reusing the function name `validateForm` **you have overwritten your function** two times. So when at some point call this method it **executes only the last implementation** of `validateForm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsut create only one `validateForm()` function and inside this function validate all your fields.

```js
function validateForm() {
 var fname = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["fname"].value;
 if (fname == "") {
  alert("Firstname must be filled out");
  return false;
 }
  var sname = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["sname"].value;
 if (sname == "") {
  alert("Surname must be filled out");
  return false;
 }
 var email = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["email"].value;
 if (email == "") {
  alert("Email must be filled out");
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="buyProductForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <fieldset id="field1">
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>

    <label for="name">Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your first name" ><br>

    <label for="name">Surname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Enter your surname"><br>

    <label for="email">Email Adress:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm() {
        var fname = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (fname == "") {
            alert("Firstname must be filled out");
            return false;
        }

        var sname = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["sname"].value;
        if (sname == "") {
            alert("Surname must be filled out");
            return false;
        }

        var email = document.forms["buyProductForm"]["email"].value;
        if (email == "") {
            alert("Email must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
```